# Eager-loading a collection in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an aggregate with the domain objects `Order` and `OrderItem`. `Order` is the aggregate root.

Given an `Order`, I want to get a specific `OrderItem` (say, number 3). The problem is that I don't want to populate up-front `Order.OrderItems`. Instead, I want to query it on demand and get just what I need.

So I need to place this code in the `Order` repository, because I need to read from my database. My question is if this is correct in a DDD context, if so, could you please give me an example of the signature I should use? I really appreciate.

Comment: Afaik. you can put these queries into a domain service or into the repo. Another solution by cqrs is having a separate read domain with these queries. Why don't want to have an Order.OrderItems?

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is just an hypothetical example. I'm trying to understand DDD. I'm not sure if I will ever encounter this scenario in real-life though. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have a list of OrderItem inside Order? What rules do you have that applies to all OrderItem within an Order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't query your domain.

An aggregate root is always returned from a repository fully constituted.

What you could implement is a specific query/read model.  In the c# world I usually simply return a `DataRow` or, if need be, a DTO:

```
public interface IOrderQuery
{
    DataRow ItemDetails(Guid orderId, Guid productId);
}
```

The above signature will change depending on your specific case.

Since it is a hypothetical situation I guess the merits of why you are doing what you are doing shouldn't matter too much ;)

Comment: "An aggregate root is always returned from a repository fully constituted." > That really made it clear, thank you!